# Excel 2016: Insert Row ABOVE find result in table

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row, listobject

I am new to programming and trying to grasp the concepts. What I am trying to accomplish:

1. Loop through first table to get a string to search for
2. Then find the first instance of that string in a second table (if it exists)
3. Then insert/copy a row (from the first table) into the second table ABOVE the row where the instance was found (in the second table)...or if no instance exists: add a new row at the bottom of the second table and insert/copy the row there.

I think I have the second part working correctly

Where I am coming up short is figuring out the ListObject approach to do this correctly. I tried utilizing an 'activecell' approach but that isn't giving me the correct location within the table. I have searched extensively and found very little on inserting or even pasting into dynamic locations within a table using the ListObject approach.

```
Dim lastRow, eachRow1, unitRow, qtyRow As Long
Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim tbl1, tbl2, tbl3 As ListObject
Dim chkFrst As Boolean
Dim qtyValue, yumItem As String
Dim qty, stockQty, calcQty As Integer
Dim lastDate, reDate As Date
Dim findRng As Range
Dim NewRow, addRow As ListRow
Set ws1 = Sheets("UPDATE")
Set ws2 = Sheets("DATA")
Set ws3 = Sheets("LOG")
Set tbl1 = ws1.ListObjects("Update_Table")
Set tbl2 = ws2.ListObjects("Data_Table")
Set tbl3 = ws3.ListObjects("Log_Table")

For unitRow = 1 To tbl1.ListRows.Count
    yumItem = tbl1.ListColumns("ITEM").DataBodyRange.Cells(unitRow, 1).Value
    Set findRng = tbl3.Range.Find(What:=yumItem)
    If findRng Is Nothing Then
        Set NewRow = tbl3.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
        NewRow.Range.RowHeight = 25
        NewRow.Range = tbl1.DataBodyRange.Cells.Range("A" & unitRow & ":O" & 
        unitRow).Value
    Else
        Application.Goto findRng, True
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlDown
        Dim crntRow As Long
        crntRow = ActiveCell.Row
        Set NewRow = tbl3.InsertRowRange.Cells.Range(crntRow)
        NewRow.Range = tbl1.DataBodyRange.Cells.Range("A" & unitRow & ":O" & 
        unitRow).Value
   End If
Next unitRow
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder? Although the code produced needs to be used with caution, it will often help get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EntireRow.Insert` with your `FindRng` range.

```
Set findRng = tbl3.Range.Find(What:=yumItem)
findRng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

<del>This will create a new row directly above your range.</del> This will shift down the found row, leaving an empty row in it's place.<sup>1</sup>

---

Only want to insert a new row for certain columns? Just replace `EntireRow` with `Columns()`. The below example will insert a row for the columns `A:C`:

```
findRng.Columns("A:C").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

---

*<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks for [clarifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344216/excel-2016-insert-row-above-find-result-in-table/49344320?noredirect=1#comment85688898_49344320) that point, Jeeped!</sub>*

Comment: *'This will create a new row directly above your range.'* Truth be told, it might be more accurate to say that the the fndRng will be pushed down leaving an empty row in its original place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insight, I was thinking I had to use ListRows.Add to coincide with the ListObject format. So inserting the row isn't a problem but I have to format the cells a certain way and need to reference the new row so I tried

```
findRng.Columns("A:O").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Set NewRow = findRng.Offset(-1, 0)
NewRow.Range.RowHeight = 25
NewRow.Range = tbl1.DataBodyRange.Cells.Range("A" & 
unitRow & ":O" & unitRow).Value
```

But now I'm getting 'wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'. How do I Set the new row?